# Как добавить функционала к своему add-on, чтобы пользователь мог сам создать "список совпадений от пользователя"?

Tags: javascript, json, addons

Есть `content_scripts.js` в манифесте к дополнению

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["js/content_scripts.js"],
      "exclude_matches": ["*://*/*"]
     ...
```

стоит исключение на все url.

С чего начать чтобы пользователь мог сам каким либо способом добавлять `location.host` в `"matches"`? Конечно же, думаю доступна на изменения  нет у дополнения. Я хочу чтобы пользователь сам решал с какими сайтами будет работать мой add-on.

---

Мне в голову только одно пришло:

`"exclude_matches": ["*://*/*"]` заменить на `"matches": ["*://*/*"]`, а весь код из `content_scripts.js` поместить в блок условного оператора `if`. Но придется подумать где список разрешенных сайтов хранить.